# Adding "No data found" message on Kendo Autocomplete with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui, autocomplete

I'm new to Kendo UI and I apologize if this is a simple question, but I am working on a site that has search functionality that uses AutoComplete to show possible results. But when there are no matches the list simply goes away, and I need there to be a message that says there are no more matches in place of that list.

I did not write the majority of this code, but all I can find associated with it is this in HTML:

input kendo-auto-complete style="width:100%" ng-model="vm.search" k-  k-data-source="vm.searchList" />

I've checked the Kendo site and there seem to be options to help with my issue, but I don't know how to implement them with AngularJS involved.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all options you can find on the KendoUI docs can be converted to be usable with AngularJS. ([Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-options-in-html))

In your case the desired option is called `noDataTemplate`. To use this configuration in HTML you have to convert it from camelCase to be dash-seperated and prefix it with `k-`.

The result should look like this: `k-no-data-template`.

Complete sample in HTML:

```
<input kendo-auto-complete k-data-source="data" k-no-data-template="'No Data available!'" />
```

Comment: I came across that answer before but it still isn't working. The top of the page mentions the widget not initializing if the attribute options are "undefined". Do i need to add any sort of data model to it to make it activate?

Comment: I've create a [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AmINO) showing an example.

Answer (score 0):

your can find the solution in this post:

[Add new Item with AngularJS](http://www.telerik.com/forums/add-new-item-with-angularjs)